# Using browser's certificate (private key) to sign some string in javascript

Tags: javascript, ssl, certificate, client-certificates

My users have some certificates (private keys) installed in their web browser. These certificates are used by the browser to authenticate the user on certain third party websites.

I would like to **sign** some string **using one of the private keys**, when the user uses/visits **my website**. Is there any JavaScript API or function, which would enable to do this?

Comment: no, cert stores are NOT system-wide in windows. IE will use the system store, but other browsers won't.

Comment: I tested this with IE and Chrome and both can see the same certs. FireFox doesn't

Comment: Anyway it doesn't matter to me if the store is system-wide or not so I've erased the part of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, you can't sign a string delivered through the web browser using Java Script and a Client certificate from the end user.

In your case the user certificates and keys are used for TLS Client Authentication:

- During the TLS Handshake the Server will request the browser to present TLS Client certificate.
- The browser will pick a suitable Client Certificate and establish the TLS connection.
- Once done, the server will deliver the content: HTML , JS, Images...
- The browser will render the page with all the elements.

The browser has an API to access the client certificates and keys but this is not exposed to the Java Script engine.